# GeoServer PrintPlugin .yaml file HorizontalAllign Error

Tags: printing, dictionary, geoserver, mapfish

I tried all versions of geoserver and print module on both windows and ubuntu. I tried both war and exe installation. I use tomcat 7 and jdk 7. But there is the same error message.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.ho.yaml.exception.YamlException: Error near line 0: Problem getting RİGHT value of enum type class org.mapfish.print.config.layout.HorizontalAlign

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.ho.yaml.exception.YamlException: Error near line 0: Problem getting RİGHT value of enum type class org.mapfish.print.config.layout.HorizontalAlign

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.ho.yaml.exception.YamlException: Error near line 0: Problem getting RİGHT value of enum type class org.mapfish.print.config.layout.HorizontalAlign
```